# Unable to upload file to Sharepoint @ Office 365 via REST

Tags: javascript, ajax, rest, sharepoint, office365

I'm having trouble creating/uploading files via Microsoft's REST API (or at least that's what they call it) for Sharepoint running on Office 365. It looks like I'm able to authenticate all right, but I'm getting **403 Forbidden** when I try to create a file. The same user can upload a file using the website.

The code I've been using can be seen on http://jsfiddle.net/Lw8hcyda/5/ . (Please note that you need to allow cross domain requests if you try to run it in your browser.)

```
    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://examplecustomer.sharepoint.com/sites/examplesite/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(\'/sites/examplesite/Documents/images\')/Files/add(url=\'testing-rest.txt\',overwrite=true)',
        type: 'POST',
        data: 'contents',
        headers: {
            'X-RequestDigest': digest
        },
        success: function (data, textStatus, jqXhr) {
            console.log('File created. :-D');
        },
        error: function (jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log('Failed to create file. Got status [' + textStatus + '] and error [' + errorThrown + '].');
        }
    });
```

Listing files using **GET** to `https://examplecustomer.sharepoint.com/sites/examplesite/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/examplesite/Documents/images')/Files` works 100% (but that doesn't require that request digest).

Getting a new request digest using **POST** to `https://examplecustomer.sharepoint.com/sites/examplesite/_api/contextinfo` also fails with **403 Forbidden**.

I've got a `X-RequestDigest` (from the page returned after logging in) that seems valid and I got values for the `FedAuth` and `rtFa` cookies.

Most of the help for using the services I've found have been various blog posts from around the Internet. In the comments there are typically a few that tell about the same problem, though I haven't seen any solutions.

Comment: From where you call the ajax ? A page inside Sharepoint Site or Sharepoint Hosted App ?

Comment: @Max: Actually, it's from an iOS app showing a local file (file://) in a webview (using Cordova). Also, during development on desktop I run in through both file:// and [http://localhost](http://localhost). Isn't that supposed to work?

Comment: During development you have used Internet Explorer I suppose, try desktop development with Chrome or Firefox and you got the error.

Comment: During development on desktop I use Chrome with the "-disable-web-security" flag enabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To me it just seems a bit light, visit this link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn769086.aspx on technet, and compare your upload function to this:

```
// Add the file to the file collection in the Shared Documents folder.
function addFileToFolder(arrayBuffer) {

    // Get the file name from the file input control on the page.
    var parts = fileInput[0].value.split('\\');
    var fileName = parts[parts.length - 1];

    // Construct the endpoint.
    var fileCollectionEndpoint = String.format(
        "{0}/_api/sp.appcontextsite(@target)/web/getfolderbyserverrelativeurl('{1}')/files" +
        "/add(overwrite=true, url='{2}')?@target='{3}'",
        appWebUrl, serverRelativeUrlToFolder, fileName, hostWebUrl);

    // Send the request and return the response.
    // This call returns the SharePoint file.
    return jQuery.ajax({
        url: fileCollectionEndpoint,
        type: "POST",
        data: arrayBuffer,
        processData: false,
        headers: {
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": jQuery("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
            "content-length": arrayBuffer.byteLength
        }
    });
}
```

Also; since calling office online from a mobile app, you should include the Authorization header "Bearer <>"

Comment: I'm not sure that element **#__REQUESTDIGEST** is present, I think is necessary an additional call for retrieve the token.

Comment: That was it, @JakobN! All I had to do was to change the "X-RequestDigest" header with "Authorization: Bearer [request digest]" and I was able to upload files!

Comment: You should update your answer to reflect the real issue here, the missing authorization header.

Answer (score 3):

As JakobN and JoyS Points out in the comments:

Changing:

```
headers: {
    'X-RequestDigest': digest
},
```

To:

```
headers: {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer '+digest
},
```

Did the trick for me! [Not the first](http://sharepointfieldnotes.blogspot.se/2014/07/uploading-large-documents-into.html) SPO authentication sudden change that has thrown me off.